# Create dynamic content causes duplicate ID error

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have an empty NavContainer and want to create dynamic views and add them to the NavContainer.

When I navigate back, I get the current page and destroy it, but when I try to navigate again to the same view, I need to create again and I get a duplicate ID error.

Example:

- I have an empty NavContainer and one button `Nav1`
- If I click on `Nav1`, I create the `view1` and add to the NavContainer,
  then I use `NavContainer.to(view1)`
- I click to the previews page and use `NavContainer.removePage(view1)`
  and `view1.destroy()`
- If I click again on `Nav1` and I get a duplicate ID error

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please, use method [destroyPages()](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.NavContainer.html#destroyPages) of sap.m.NavContainer instead of removePage() method in order to avoid duplicate id error.

Comment: Can I destroy only one page?